# How to use "after" properly?

Tags: grammaticality

Here is one sentence from BBC World News:

> No signals have come from the lander **after** it made the final descent.

I looked up the word *after* in LDOCE, it can be used in the present perfect tense, the past perfect tense. But I did not find any sentence like the mentioned one. And there is another one:

> A Scottish boxer has died **after** being injured in a bout on Thursday.

Comment: I think you mean *"No signals have come ..."*.

Comment: Sorry,  a wrong spelling. It is "signal"

Answer (score 1):

> No signals have come from the lander after it made the final descent.

I would say the sentence from the BBC is not quite grammatical, because I understand "after it made the final descent" to refer to the period of time following its descent, which time is in the past; it does not extend to the present.

The word *after* in **after it made** does *not* function like an `after` operator in a data query language:

**select * from employees where dateHired after 20120101.**

which would include employees hired today.

The time phrases in a present perfect construction cannot exclude the present.

I would have written:

> No signals have come from the lander **since** it made the final descent.

P.S. But if the speaker understands **after** to be perfectly synonymous with **since**, the BBC sentence will strike the speaker's ear as grammatical.

Comment: This sentence: A Scottish boxer has died after being injured in a bout on Thursday. Is it acceptable?

Comment: My ear understands "after *being* injured" differently than "after he *was* injured". The being-injured state extends to the present with the former, or at least does not exclude the present, and so, for me, the second sentence is not jarring in the way the first sentence was.